# Finding $g_i:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb R$ s.t $f(x)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i\cdot g_i(x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, intuition

> Let $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ differntiable and $f(0)=0$. Prove exist $g_i$ s.t for $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n):f(x)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i\cdot g_i(x)$. hint:$f(x)=\int\limits_0^1f\prime(tx)dt$.

I dont have any idea how to solve it. maybe we can build $g_i=f(x_i\cdot x)$ but im not sure it may help since I cannot take one time $\int f(x_1\cdot x)dx_1$ and in another $\int f(x_n\cdot x)dx_n$).

how can I build the sequence of functions and furthermore, what is the intuition for this type of questions involves building functions $\varphi:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ based on given condition with sums or diffrentiablity or partial derivatives?

Comment: Hint: Chain rule for $\frac{d}{dt}f(t\cdot x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the chain rule we shall have $$f'(tx)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}(tx)x_k,$$ put $g_k(x):=\int_0^1 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}(tx)dt.$ This is a form of *Hadamard's lemma*. I actually don't understand what you mean by your second question, which is very imprecise, but this lemma is used to prove, say, that every derivation of $C^\infty(\mathbf{R}^n)$ is a first order linear partial differential operator.

Comment: isnt it supposed to be $\partial x_k$ in the denominator?

Comment: well some people use upper indices instead of lower ones, but I will change the notation

Comment: but for $f(x1,\dots,x_n)=\sum x_i$ taking these $g_i$s won't help (I get $f(x)\overset{?}{=}0.5f(x)$)

Comment: you have to differentiate first and then plug in $tx$, not conversly!

Comment: but in that notation didn't you mean $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}(tx_1,\dots,tx_n)$ relating t as a constant? how can one differentiate and then plug the t?

Comment: I don't know how to address this question, it's just the chain rule: the function we are differentiating is the composite $[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbf{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbf{R}$ where the first map is $t\mapsto tx$. The chain rule says that the derivative is the derivative of $f$ composed with $tx$ dot product the derivative of $t\mapsto tx$

Comment: Why should $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}$ be integrable without additional assumptions on $f$?

Comment: Both here and in the original question, the notation is really horrid. $f'(tx)$ does not mean the same thing as $g'(t)$ where $g(x)=f(tx)$.