# $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ has expansion $\sum_i g_i(x)x^i$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Problem 2-35 on page 34 of Spivak's *Calculus on Manifolds* states

> If $f: \mathbb{R}^n: \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and $f(0) =0$,
>   prove that there exist $g_i: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
>   $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n x^ig_i(x)$.
>
> Hint: if $h_x(t) = f(tx)$, then $f(x)
>  = \int_0^1 h_x'(t)$.

I understand the answer he wants, but hasn't he left out a hypothesis that would ensure $h_x'(t)$ is integrable? (For instance the continuity of $df$.)

Secondly, I'm wondering if this theorem is used anywhere. Perhaps in differential geometry it might be useful to write locally $f \in C^\infty (M)$ as $\sum_i g_i(x) x_i$ for some coordinates $x_i$.

Comment: A keyword for your second question: [Malgrange preparation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malgrange_preparation_theorem)

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588411/finding-g-i-mathbbrn-to-mathbb-r-s-t-fx-sum-limits-i-1nx-i-cdot-g-i?rq=1 . As to where it is used, it is used in Morse theory and the many critical results coming from Morse theory. This question was asked with this exact wording somewhere, though if it was on MSE it was deleted I guess.

Comment: @PVAL The link you gave doesn't address the notion of $f$ needing to be $C^1$, nor does it talk about applications.

Comment: You don't need the continuity of the derivative. See this question:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1156131/a-decomposition-of-a-differentiable-function/1156186#1156186

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are quite right that you need integrability of the derivative. But the answer is quite simple: on page 28 he writes: *First of all, we will be interested almost exclusively in functions $f:\mathbf{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbf{R}^n$ which are $C^\infty$ (that is, each component function $f$ possesses continuous partial derivatives of all orders); sometimes we will use the words "differentiable" or "smooth" to mean $C^\infty$".* So when he says "differentiable" it is understood "of class $C^\infty$".

The main application of this result (Hadamard's lemma) I know of is to show that the space of vector fields $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ is canonically isomorphic to the space of derivations $\mathrm{Der}_{\mathbf{R}}(C^\infty(M))$. Variations of the result you mention appear later on in Spivak, when he gives a coordinate free proof of $L_X Y=[X,Y]$.

Answer (score 0):

I remember this problem. I'm also working through Calc on Manifolds right now. 
Following the hint, we have:

$ h_{\vec{x}}(t) = f(t\vec{x}) $ implies $ f(\vec{x}) = \displaystyle \int_0^1 h_{\vec{x}}'(t) dt $

Then we may write:

$ f(\vec{x}) = \displaystyle \int_0^1 h_{\vec{x}}'(t) dt = \displaystyle \int_0^1 f'(t\vec{x}) dt $

Where $f'(t\vec{x})$ here denotes an ordinary derivative with respect to $t$. Now, we may expand this expression using the chain rule (I will use Spivak's notation since I assume you are familiar with it):

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 f'(t\vec{x}) dt = \displaystyle \int_0^1 \displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^n x^j D_j f(t\vec{x}) dt $

And finally since we are integrating with respect to $t$:

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^n x^j D_j f(t\vec{x}) dt =\displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^n x^j\displaystyle \int_0^1 D_j f(t\vec{x}) dt$

Now simply let $ g_j (\vec{x})=\displaystyle \int_0^1 D_j f(t\vec{x}) dt$

And we have: $f(\vec{x}) = \displaystyle \sum_{j=0}^n x^j g_j (\vec{x})$

As desired. I recall having a bit of trouble with this one. Also, as you can see, differentiability of $f$ is sufficient to ensure the existence of such $g_j$. As for your final question, once I get further in the book, I may be able to answer it for you, but as of right now, I cannot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually understand how to solve the problem. My question, though, is why should, for example, $D_j f(t\vec{x})$ be integrable without further assumptions on $f$?

Comment: If $D_j f(t\vec{x})$ is not integrable with respect to $t$ for some $j$, then we must have that the ordinary derivative with respect to $t$ of $f(t\vec{x})$ is not integrable, which by the fundamental theorem of calculus is not possible. This is how I understand it.

Comment: That is true...not all differentiable functions are such that $\int_a^b f'(t) = f(b)-f(a)$, because sometimes $f'$ is not integrable. See here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6711/integrability-of-derivatives

Comment: Hmmm...that is very interesting. Then I suppose you are correct. I guess requiring that $f \in C^1$ would suffice. I find that counter-intuitive. Actually, $f \in C^1$ can be replaced with a weaker statement, we could require the set of all $t$ at which $f'(t\vec{x})$ is discontinuous to have measure 0, hence $f'(t\vec{x})$ would be Riemann integrable yet still have an infinite number of discontinuities.