# A decomposition of a differentiable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-writing

this time I want to solve this problem:

Let  $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable (**may be not in** $C^{1}$) and $f(0)=0$, show that there exists $g_{i} : \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that:

$$f(x)= \sum_{i=1}^{n} x^{i}g_i $$

then, I thought in Taylor decomposition, but the thing is that I can't use that here because I need $f$ to be k+1 differentiable (and well we saw that in Calculus III, but not here in multivariable Analysis that I think it could be a little problem) and I don't have that hypothesis,in spite of that the formula seems to me like the first degree polynomial of indeed the Taylor decomposition, but I don't how to proceed now, Can someone help me please?, thanks a lot in advance :)

**I was thinking in some of this sort:**

$g_i(x)= \frac{f^{i}(x)}{x^{i}}$

**but how to proceed when** $x^{i}=0$?

Comment: Is $g_1$ supposed to be $g_i$? If $x$ is a vector, what does $x^i$ mean?

Comment: I am sorry these are the components of the vector $x$

Answer (score 3):

*Note:* The displayed formula in your question  should read
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\> g_i(x)\ .$$

This can be done with *continuous $g_i\,$, under the sole assumption that $f$ is differentiable at $0$*.

*Proof.* Put
$$a_i:=f_{.i}(0)\ .$$
Then $f$ can be written as
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i x_i + p(x)\ ,\qquad \lim_{x\to0}{p(x)\over |x|}=0\ .$$
Define 
$$h_i(x):=\left\{\eqalign{{x_i\over|x|}{p(x)\over|x|}&\qquad(x\ne0)\cr 0\qquad&\qquad(x=0)\cr}\right.$$
for $1\leq i\leq n$. Then the $h_i$ are continuous at $0$, and $$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i h_i(x)={\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\over |x|^2}\>p(x)=p(x)\qquad\forall x\ .$$  It follows that the functions
$$g_i(x):=a_i+h_i(x)\qquad(1\leq i\leq n)$$
do the job.