# Do we need differentiability in problem 2-35 in Spivak?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, proof-verification

In *Calculus on Manifolds* by Spivak, Problem 2-35 goes as follows:

> If $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and $f(0) =0$,
>   prove that there exist $g_i: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
>   $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n x^ig_i(x)$.

My question is: do we really need differentiability? Can we just let
$$g_i(x)=\begin{cases} {f(x)}/\left({x^i\cdot\left|\{j|x^j\neq 0\}\right|}\right) & x^i\neq 0\\
0 & x^i=0 \end{cases}$$

so that $$x^ig_i(x)=\begin{cases} {f(x)}/\left({\left|\{j|x^j\neq 0\}\right|}\right) & x^i\neq 0\\
0 & x^i=0 \end{cases}$$

so $\sum_{i=1}^n x^ig_i(x)={f(x)}$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1107081/f-mathbbrn-to-mathbbr-has-expansion-sum-i-g-ixxi?rq=1

Comment: It is not a duplicate. While his question regards the same problem in Spivak's book, he still asks a different question: whether the hypothesis of the problem is enough to ensure the integrabilty of a function suggested in the hint. I ask if we actually need this function at all, and whether we need $f$ to be differentiable.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1156131/279515

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought about it and I'm fairly certain this solution is correct, and that Spivak must have meant to say the $g_i$ should be continuous.

Of course, there are still problems with this exercise, since he also forgot to assume the functions $h_x^\prime(t)$ given in the hint are integrable (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1107081/f-mathbbrn-to-mathbbr-has-expansion-sum-i-g-ixxi?noredirect=1&lq=1)), but that's something else...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need differentiability. Otherwise take $n = 1$ and $f(x) = \sqrt{|x|}$.

Comment: Can't we just let $g_1=\sqrt{|x|}/x$ for $x\neq 0$ (and $g_1(0)=0$)? Then $f(x)=x\cdot g(x)$...

Comment: I had assumed that the $g_i$ were supposed to be continuous. Without continuity I think something like what you describe always works but it's not useful for much.

Comment: You're probably right, Spivak must have forgotten to write that. (Although in this particular case my $g$ is still continuous).