# Finding specific functions $g_i$ in $f(x)= \sum_{i=1}^{n} x^{i}g_i $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let  $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable (**may be not in** $C^{1}$) and $f(0)=0$, show that there exists $g_{i} : \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that:

$$f(x)= \sum_{i=1}^{n} x^{i}g_i $$

I was thinking in some of this sort:

$g_i(x)= \frac{f^{i}(x)}{x^{i}}$

but how to proceed when $x^{i}=0$?

I have checked the answer posted here

[Finding $g_i:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb R$ s.t $f(x)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i\cdot g_i(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588411/finding-g-i-mathbbrn-to-mathbb-r-s-t-fx-sum-limits-i-1nx-i-cdot-g-i)

but I think there are some things like how do you know that the integral exists? that is why my idea is the above one. Thanks in advance

NOTE: $x^i$ is the i-th component